# Presented UIViewController can't present a UIAlertController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uialertcontroller, presentviewcontroller

When the submit button is clicked in my application, the `SubmitViewController` is presented over the active view controller to display upload progress.

When an error notification is received, it should display an Alert with the error and dismiss itself.

The problem is that no Alert gets displayed because `self.navigationController` is equal to `nil`. How can I present the Alert in that case?

I can't use the storyboard to instantiate `SubmitViewController` as some may suggest, as it is not part of a storyboard.

View controller used to present `SubmitViewController`:

```
-(void)submitBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    SubmitViewController *submitViewController = [SubmitViewController new];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:submitViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

`SubmitViewController.swift`:

```
@objc func submitErrorNotification(_ notification:Notification) {
    self.unsubscribe()

    let title:String = notification.userInfo!["title"] as! String
    let message:String = notification.userInfo!["message"] as! String

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

    if (self.navigationController == nil) {
        NSLog("Error: navigation controller is nil");// THIS error occurs
    }

    self.navigationController?.present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)

    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to present the alert controller on the navigation controller?  Why don't you just present it on your `SubmitViewController` instance and dismiss that in the action handler

Comment: @Paulw11 that is my go to solution now. I need to present it on navigation controller so I can dismiss the underlying view controller and replace it with a different view controller.

Comment: Then you should probably use a delegation pattern so that the submit view controller can tell a delegate that there was an error and the delegate can decide what to do

Answer (score 0):

Why your using alert keyword in :

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Try this :

```
SubmitViewController *myViewController = [SubmitViewController new];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Just by mistake, nothing to do with the problem.